How can I create a python program that organizes CSV into combinations?
I was directed to this forum by the users at stack overflow as they informed me it didnt fit there.
Im trying to create a program that would input a csv file with two lists of plate thicknesses, in this case tungsten and quartz, and their ID numbers. Then sort them, returning a CSV file with "stacks" of 8 plates (4 tungsten and 4 quartz) that are as close to the goal thickness as possible.
Mathematically I have an idea to break it down into sections, ie. Take a quartz plate and subtract it from a quarter of the goal thickness then find a tungsten plate that is the closest to that difference. Repeating until I have a list of pairs of tungsten and quartz.
I would then repeat with these pair subtracting their sum from half of the goal thickness matching them to another pair of tungsten and quarts returning a list of "halves" (2quartz 2tungsten)
Doing this one more time with the halves returning a csv file with packages of plates optimized to fit with eachother to get as close to the goal thickness.
Its been a long time since I worked with python and I was looking for some advice on how to make this come together so I apologize if I havent used the proper terms.
I have done some reading and found examples of the stable marriage problem but my issue is that Im working with unequat data sets, specifically there are more tungsten plates than quartz.
Im also lost whether its an appropriate application compared to concepts like the knapsack problem.

How do you propose to handle the unequal number of plates? Do you want to stick with stacks of eight (four each) and have leftover plates, do you want to allow stacks of eight with one or more stacks containing mainly/exclusively tungsten plates, or do you want to allow stacks smaller than eight?

I was hoping to use the quartz as a bias since its a lower number like a loop where it repeats until the quartz all has its matching tungsten plate to its "pair". Each completed stack must have 4 quartz and 4 tungsten so I figure Id some how weed out the remaining tungsten after the first stage where each plate of quartz is matched with a plate of tungsten.

Let $Q$ and $T$ be the number of quartz and tungsten plates respectively,
$q_{i}$ and $t_{i}$ the thickness of the $i$-th quartz plate and
the $i$-th tungsten plate respectively, and $G$ the thickness goal
for a stack of eight plates. These are all parameters. I am going
to assume that all stacks must contain four plates of each type, that
excess tungsten plates are discarded, and that as many stacks as possible
must be formed (i.e., no skipping stacks just because they would be
far off in thickness). Given that there are more tungsten plates than
quartz, the number of stacks to be made is $S=\left\lfloor \frac{Q}{4}\right\rfloor .$
A mixed integer linear programming model for the problem would use
binary variables $x_{ij}$ for whether quartz plate $i$ is used (1)
or not (0) in stack $j$ and $y_{ij}$ for whether tungsten plate
$i$ is used in stack $j.$ We also need nonnegative continuous variables
$d_{j}^{+}$ and $d_{j}^{-}$ for the amount that the thickness of
stack $j$ exceeds or falls below the goal.
The constraints are as follows.

Every stack contains four quartz plates:
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{Q}x_{ij}=4\quad j=1,\dots,S
$$
Every stack contains four tungsten plates:
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{T}y_{ij}=4\quad\forall j=1,\dots,S
$$
Every quartz plate is assigned to exactly one stack:
$$
\sum_{j=1}^{S}x_{ij}=1\quad\forall i=1,\dots,Q
$$
Every tungsten plate is assigned to at most one stack:
$$
\sum_{j=1}^{S}y_{ij}\le1\quad\forall i=1,\dots,T
$$
The thickness of a stack is the goal plus or minus any deviations:
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{Q}q_{i}x_{ij}+\sum_{i=1}^{T}t_{i}y_{ij}+d_{j}^{-}-d_{j}^{+}=G\quad\forall j=1,\dots,S
$$

That leaves us with selecting an objective function. One possibility
is to minimize the sum of the absolute values of the stack deviations
from the goal thickness:
$$
\min\ \sum_{j=1}^{S}\left(d_{j}^{+}+d_{j}^{-}\right)
$$
Another possibility is to minimize the single worst deviation of any
stack. For that, we introduce one more nonnegative variable $z$ along
with the constraints $d_{j}^{+}\le z$ and $d_{j}^{-}\le z$ for
all stacks $j$ and then minimize $z.$ There are other possibilities
for the objective function. If deviations above goal thickness and
deviations below goal thickness are not equally bad, you can weight
the deviation variables to reflect their relative importance.

For the minimax objective, you can strengthen the formulation by imposing $d_j^+ + d_j^- \le z$ instead of two separate inequalities.
